# Error While calling "from haystack.document_stores import ElasticsearchDocumentStore"

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science, haystack

I was trying to install **'farm-haystack**' and **'farm'** (farm-haystack==1.21.2
farm==0.2.0) on ubuntu 22.04. after installation trying to call elastic search by the below command :
**"from haystack.document_stores import ElasticsearchDocumentStore"**

**but its gives me below error:**

### Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor

PydanticSchemaGenerationError             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 1
----> 1 from haystack.document_stores import ElasticsearchDocumentStore

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/haystack/**init**.py:10
6 **version**: str = str(metadata.version("farm-haystack"))
9 import haystack.silenceable_tqdm  # Needs to be imported first to wrap TQDM for all following modules
---> 10 from haystack.schema import Document, Answer, Label, MultiLabel, Span, EvaluationResult, TableCell
11 from haystack.nodes.base import BaseComponent
12 from haystack.pipelines.base import Pipeline

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/haystack/schema.py:43
38 ContentTypes = Literal["text", "table", "image", "audio"]
39 FilterType = Dict[str, Union[Dict[str, Any], List[Any], str, int, float, bool]]
42 @dataclass
---> 43 class Document:
44     id: str
45     content: Union[str, DataFrame]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/dataclasses.py:213, in dataclass(_cls, init, repr, eq, order, unsafe_hash, frozen, config, validate_on_init, kw_only, slots)
210 if _cls is None:
211     return create_dataclass
--> 213 return create_dataclass(_cls)
...
PydanticSchemaGenerationError: Unable to generate pydantic-core schema for <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>. Set `arbitrary_types_allowed=True` in the model_config to ignore this error or implement `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` on your type to fully support it.

If you got this error by calling handler() within `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` then you likely need to call `handler.generate_schema(<some type>)` since we do not call `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` on `<some type>` otherwise to avoid infinite recursion.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/u/schema-for-unknown-type

Please help me resolve this matter
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have figured it out already or not. However, I ran into similar problem. I didn't touch anything on my previous conda environment. All of a sudden, I was getting the same error.

**What solved for me is** -

1. Created a new environment.
2. `pip install farm-haystack[all]`

That's pretty much it. Wish you all the best!